# Unable to start the Jenkins server, getting below error

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins local server is not working, tried uninstall and install but still the issue is there. please check the logs and suggest the solution for it.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:159)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
    Caused: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2232)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3969)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4829)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4834)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:136)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:533)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:160)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:123)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder.<init>(ExtensionFinder.java:291)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:642)
        at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.instance(IndexItem.java:181)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz._find(ExtensionFinder.java:703)
        at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.find(ExtensionFinder.java:689)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:349)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:381)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:317)
        at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:183)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.onInitMilestoneAttained(Jenkins.java:1161)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1.onAttained(InitReactorRunner.java:84)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.lambda$onAttained$3(ReactorListener.java:102)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.run(ReactorListener.java:109)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.onAttained(ReactorListener.java:102)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1164)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:962)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:295)
    Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:312)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by changing the Java version to 1.8.0_301.
Path to Java can be changed in the file C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.xml

[image]

Comment: Hi, please rather give explanation of what you did and commands than uploading a picture of text . For example : switch into Java installation directory ```$ cd  'C:\programs\bin"```  use  \``for code examples ``

Comment: You can download Java from https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp if needed.

I already had it. So, I opened the file C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.xml in text editor and I replaced the path to Java folder in node executable as on the screenshot. Path is 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe' on my PC. Also, you can see parameters on the screenshot which I am using. Possible it will help you because I do not know which parameters you are using.